# 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' options -not aligned

Tags: python, widget, django-forms

I have a multiple choice field, something like this:

```
ft = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

which can have any no. of options. The problem is those do not display in an aligned manner but rather are done randomly and look clumsy. This messes up the whole look of the form. I am open for a django solution to this, probably by overriding the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget or even by adding a new class in CSS. I cannot change the .aligned in django/contrib/admin, as mentioned in some other site.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can specify a CSS-class for the checkbox widget which will give you more control over the layout. If this doesn't help, please be more specific about what is not looking OK.

Comment: @Mikael, Thnx for response. As i said the options are not aligned in a proper manner, like some line has 2options, some has 3.. for an option checkbox is on first line and related option is pushed to second line. And specifying a CSS class     is a good solution, but excuse my ignorance, I do not know how you would define a class, which can align the options. Lil help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK I see. Would it be possible to edit your post to show how the options are displayed and how you would like them to be displayed?

Comment: Quite simple @Mikael.. I would like to have 2 or 3 options in a line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue..
We can add a CSS element[class or id] as below..

```
#field-checks ul
{
width:700px;
}
#field-checks ul li{
display :block;
width:200px;
float:left;
}
```

Now use the element

```
"field-checks"
```

in the html file.

Here the main thing is

```
dipslay:block
```

You can set the width as you want depending on how many fields you need in a line. As I needed 3 I used 700 and 200, if u need only two you could use (say) 800 and 400.
Let me know if this works for you, or you have a better way than this :)